# eclipse stuck for more than 10 min on 'Launching : Starting virtual machine ' in progress bar

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using .launch file to start my java application. when I start application using run as on .launch file. it is taking more than 10min to start java application although I have 16gb of RAM. in progress bar it is stuck at 92% and

message saying 'Launching : Starting virtual machine' .

I tried many option like increasing param heap size but no luck.

Comment: Pls, edit the question and add information on the OS you are one, and also add the exact version of Eclipse you are trying to start.